# Отправка GET запроса на сервер с получением данных

Tags: javascript, api, rest, get

Всем привет!

Необходимо отправить **GET** запрос на сервера ВКонтакте, по следующему url:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN
```

**В гугле нашёл такой способ:**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN',false);
request.onload = function() {
    alert(request.responseText);
}

request.send();
```

**Выдаёт ошибку:**

```
networkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
```

Может кто знает альтернативные способы как это можно сделать в JS?

**Попробовал через Fetch отправить GET запрос:**

```
fetch('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN')
  .then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
```

**С Fetch ошибка такая:**

```
1.Access to fetch at **URL**
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
2.  GET **url** net::ERR_FAILED
3. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы сам не сервер, только через php можно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe получается что никак нельзя на JS такое сделать? Зачем тогда **Fetch** , **XMLHttpRequest**?

Comment: добавьте в fetch mode: 'no-cors' => `fetch('GET', 'https://...', {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(...)`

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо, результат такой: ```[object Promise]```. а в консоль вывелось это: ```Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at```, строка на которую была вызвана ошибка: ```  alert(response.json()) ;``` в ``` .then((response) => {
  alert(response.json());
})}```

Comment: замените alert этот на console.log(response)

Comment: @InDevX добавил в вопрос скриншот, что выводится с  console.log(response.json())

Comment: А, ошибка была на repsonse.json() на метод json, без него ошибки нет, но выводится +- тоже самое

Comment: тогда так  -> [https://qna.habr.com/q/813265](https://qna.habr.com/q/813265) пробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отправить запрос через обычный `fetch` - [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN')
  .then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
```

Comment: Fetch надо устанавливать, или как вообще? Только не бейте, я не js разработчик))

Comment: Нет, FetchAPI - встроенный в JavaScript интерфейс

Comment: спасибо, сделал вот так ```fetch('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN')
  .then((response) => {
  alert(response.json());
})``` и не работает

Comment: Точнее, в функцию это всё закинул, и на кнопку повесил, не работает

Comment: Надеюсь, вы не забыли указать свой токен в URL?

Comment: токен не забыл)

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Попробуйте просто перейти по этой ссылке в браузере (ведь это тоже GET запрос) и посмотрите, что выдаст JSON

Comment: всё правильно выдаёт

Comment: response":[{"first_name":"Lindsey","id":210700286,"last_name":"Stirling"}]}

Comment: я обновил вопрос, добавив полную ошибку